# Зачем нужен redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Сегодня с коллегой возникла небольшая дискуссия, я утверждал, что redux-thunk очень удобная надстройка (middleware) над redux и позволяет создавать асинхронные экшены.
Коллега возразил, зачем нужен redux-thunk, когда можно сделать вот так:

```
export function load(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    store.dispatch(getProfileSuccess({id: 1}));
  }, 3000)
}
```

Т.е он импортит store в определенный файл проекта и вызывает несколько экшенов

По началу я впал в ступор, действительно, зачем redux-thunk, если можно испортить стор, но позже проанализировав ситуацию, пришел к выводу, что асинхронные экшены, например как в примере выше загрузка профиля должна иметь 3 состояния:

- старт загрузки профиля (для отображения лоадера)
- данные профиля успешно загружены
- возникла ошибка при загрузке данных
  исходя из этого, если действовать по методу коллеги, необходимо создавать для каждого действия отдельную функцию (экшены)

Вот пример с использованием redux-thunk

```
export function getProfile () => {
  return dispatch => {
    // диспатчим лоадер
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE_START,
      payload: true
    })

    axios.get('/user')
      .then(res => {
        // успешно получили данные
        dispatch({
          type: GET_PROFILE_SECCUESS
          payload: res.data
        })
      })
      .cath(err => {
        // Ошибка...
        dispatch({
          type: GET_PROFILE_ERROR
          payload: true
        })
      })
    }
 }
```

Преимущества redux-thunk очевидны, и больше всего мне нравится то, что с помощью redux-thunk всю логику можно хранить в экшенах и тем самым разгрузить компоненты, это одновременно делает проект чище, ведь логика будет находится внутри экшенов, вместо того, чтобы импортить стор в разные части проекта

Что вы скажите, какое мнение верно, и имеет ли права на жизнь предложенное коллегой решение?